# Windows Phone Runtime pathicon runtime vs designtime

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I’m working on a WP8.1 runtime app (using the universal app template).
I’ve created an appbar with a togglebutton. The button icon is a PathIcon.

in designtime (both Blend and VS2013) the button looks exactly what I expect it to look like but at runtime the path stretches out so it fills the circle of the button.

is this difference between designtime and runtime a known issue and is there a workaround so that my button looks how it’s supposed to look at runtime?

It looks good on every resolution in Blend so it's not a scaling issue

designtime: [image: designtime]

runtime: [image: runtime]

the XAML for the button:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarToggleButton Label="HQ">
        <AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
            <PathIcon HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Data="M21.0007,6.25 C6.3752,1.125 5.25043,16.6091 5.62518,19.5 C5.9215,21.7858 6.25018,10.75 16.0005,12.875 C19.8337,13.7104 24.1247,19.3755 20.3747,23.0006 C20.1689,23.1995 18.7133,17.0212 13.6254,19.5002 C8.75026,21.8755 13.0958,28.4331 12.8234,28.4006 C5.88184,27.5722 0.5,21.6646 0.5,14.5 C0.5,6.76801 6.76801,0.5 14.5,0.5 C19.153,0.5 23.0847,2.9988 25.2497,6.50016 C25.7361,7.28663 25.9271,7.98672 26.2501,8.87522 C26.75,10.2503 22.9202,6.92261 21.0007,6.25 z" />
        </AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
    </AppBarToggleButton>
</CommandBar>
```

Comment: What happens when you remove HorizontalAlignment="Center" and VerticalAlignment="Center"?

Comment: When adding this code to an UAP, and running it on Windows it shows the expected result as shown in design time. (Non reproducible)

Comment: removing the alignments doesn't change anything, I edited the code in the first post to show the entire snippet.

Corstian, I just tried it in a blank app, had the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test with a PathIcon, but you can just a Path just fine:

```
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarToggleButton Label="HQ">
        <Path VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              Fill="White" Stroke="White" 
              Data="M21.0007,6.25 C6.3752,1.125 5.25043,16.6091 5.62518,19.5 C5.9215,21.7858 6.25018,10.75 16.0005,12.875 C19.8337,13.7104 24.1247,19.3755 20.3747,23.0006 C20.1689,23.1995 18.7133,17.0212 13.6254,19.5002 C8.75026,21.8755 13.0958,28.4331 12.8234,28.4006 C5.88184,27.5722 0.5,21.6646 0.5,14.5 C0.5,6.76801 6.76801,0.5 14.5,0.5 C19.153,0.5 23.0847,2.9988 25.2497,6.50016 C25.7361,7.28663 25.9271,7.98672 26.2501,8.87522 C26.75,10.2503 22.9202,6.92261 21.0007,6.25 z" />
    </AppBarToggleButton>
</CommandBar>
```

Comment: getting closer with this, but this seems to add a second circle to the icon that won't move
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2vdr18n.jpg

Comment: Must've missed something because this works now, thanks!